# Preloader enquanto o site carrega

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou fazendo um hotsite, ele é one page, e é um pouco pesado, com algumas imagens. Queria fazer um preloader com %, antes de carregar todo o conteúdo.

Com:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
alert('carregou');
})
```

Eu consigo saber quando o site todo carregou, mas como antes disso ir verificando a porcentagem?

Comment: dê uma olhada no [pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/).

Comment: Valeu @renan ,sabe teria algum jeito de eu pegar o valor do progresso? não posso usar um template deles...

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de fazer isso é colocar todo o código JS essencial no `<header>` do browser, fazendo com que ele seja necessariamente carregado antes mesmo do resto da página ser montado, e colocar todos os JS não essenciais no final do `<body>`, significando que eles só vão ser carregados no final.

Uma variante interessante seria usar o [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) para carregar os arquivos JS de forma dinâmica e assíncrona.

Dê uma olhada no meu projeto [retro-game-editor](http://rge.haroldo-ok.com/app/), ele tem uns scripts bem pesados e usa o require.js para carregar dinamicamente o que ele precisa; tem inclusive um preloader bem leve implementado. Repositório no GitHub: https://github.com/haroldo-ok/retro-game-editor

Já para implementar uma barra de progresso, seria mais complicado, mas perfeitamente possível. Talvez esse post lhe ajude, em parte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595289/679240

Comment: Desconhecia essa informação da prioridade no carregamento, achei que o resultado era o mesmo, gostei de saber. É uma informação útil.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa colocar o conteúdo pesado da sua página em um container, um div por exemplo, e a image de loading em outro, assim:

```
<div id="carregando"></div>
<div id="conteudo">
   ... aqui vai o conteúdo do site ...
</div>
```

Então você exibe o div com a imagem e esconde o div com o conteúdo.
No evendo document.ready, quando todo o documento estiver carregado, você inverte, esconde a imagem e exibe o conteúdo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#carregando').show();
   $('#conteudo').hide();


   $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#carregando').hide();
      $('#conteudo').show();
});
</script>
```

A imagem você seta no css, e deixe com `position: absolute` para posicionar onde você quiser:

```
#carregando {
   background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyxU.gif") center no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   widht: 100%
}
```

Basicamente é isso.

Comment: Isso eu sei, como disse na minha pergunta. Eu precisaria mostrar a % do carregamento, e não só colocar um preloader falso (um gif ou algo do genero)

Comment: você só consegue colocar % se puder calcular o % de carga dos itens, uma chamada ajax por exemplo, só link de referência de imagem não dá pra fazer isso. Se for uma sequência de chamadas ajax basta calcular o % de cada uma e alterar no div com aguarde. Agora se você já sabia como exibir o aguarde, poderia ter dito dito antes, dai eu postaria outro conteúdo.

Comment: Oi, desculpa se minha pergunta não foi clara, mas eu coloquei tudo isso nela.

Comment: Tranquilo, só quis dizer sobre a parte de mostrar a imagem, é que no seu código não aparece, por isso coloquei na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acabei usando o Pace, mais detalhes [aqui](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome)